# Does anyone know why my tkinter window wont open?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have been trying to program a simple GUI on tkinter. On older versions of python it has been working but when I'm working on my home computer on python 3.10 it does not work.
My code is as follows.

```
from tkinter import *

import inputs
from settings import *
from setcolor import *


class GuiRun:
    def run_gui():
        WIN = Tk()
        WIN.grid()
        WIN.title("Random Explosion Menu")
        WIN.configure(bg="#282a2b")

        #Row 0
        shape_opt_label = Label(WIN, text=GUI_SHAPE_TEXT, bg="#282a2b", fg="white")
        shape_opt_label.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,pady=2)
        
        #Row 1
        shape_entry = Entry(WIN, width=60, borderwidth=3)
        shape_entry.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=3)

        #Row 2
        color_opt_label = Label(WIN, text=GUI_COLOR_TEXT, bg="#282a2b", fg="white")
        color_opt_label.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=2)        

        #Row 3
        color_entry = Entry(WIN, width=60, borderwidth=3)
        color_entry.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=3)

        #Row 4
        rand_color_button = Button(WIN, text="Random Color", width=25, bg="#47494a", fg="white",
                                   command=lambda: GuiRun.set_color_val("rand_hex_color"))
        rand_color_button.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=2,pady=2)        
        
        warm_color_button = Button(WIN, text="Warm Colors", width=25, bg="#47494a", fg="white",
                                   command=lambda: GuiRun.set_color_val("rand_hex_color"))
        warm_color_button.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=2, pady=2)

        #Row 5
        cold_color_button = Button(WIN, text="Cold Colors", width=25, bg="#47494a", fg="white",
                                   command=lambda: GuiRun.set_color_val("rand_hex_color"))
        cold_color_button.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=2, pady=2)


        bubble_color_button = Button(WIN, text="Bubblegum Colors", width=25, bg="#47494a", fg="white",
                                     command=lambda: GuiRun.set_color_val("rand_hex_color"))
        bubble_color_button.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=2, pady=2)
        
        #Row 
        line_opt_label = Label(WIN, text=GUI_LINE_TEXT, bg="#282a2b", fg="white")
        line_opt_label.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=5, pady=2)        

        #Row 
        line_entry = Entry(WIN, width=60, borderwidth=3)
        line_entry.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=5, pady=3)

        #Row 4
        straight_line_button = Button(WIN, text="Random Color", width=25, bg="#47494a", fg="white",
                                   command=lambda: GuiRun.set_color_val("rand_hex_color"))
        straight_line_button.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=2,pady=2)        
        
        curved_line_button = Button(WIN, text="Warm Colors", width=25, bg="#47494a", fg="white",
                                   command=lambda: GuiRun.set_color_val("rand_hex_color"))
        curved_line_button.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=2, pady=2)

        #Row 5
        cold_color_button = Button(WIN, text="Cold Colors", width=25, bg="#47494a", fg="white",
                                   command=lambda: GuiRun.set_color_val("rand_hex_color"))
        cold_color_button.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=2, pady=2)


        bubble_color_button = Button(WIN, text="Bubblegum Colors", width=25, bg="#47494a", fg="white",
                                     command=lambda: GuiRun.set_color_val("rand_hex_color"))
        bubble_color_button.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=2, pady=2)

        #Row 7
        input_collect = Button(WIN, text="Collect Inputs", width=50, height=2, borderwidth=3,
                               bg="#47494a", fg="white", command=lambda: inputs.GetInputs.get_inputs(shape_entry, color_entry, line_entry))
        input_collect.grid(row=8, column=0, padx=5, pady=3)

        button_exit = Button(WIN, text="Exit", width=50, height=2, borderwidth=3,
                             bg="#47494a", fg="white", command=quit)
        button_exit.grid(row=9, column=0, padx=5, pady=3)

    def set_color_val(x):
        global color_value
        color_value = SetColor.x

    def set_line_val(y):
        global run
        run = y

GuiRun.run_gui()
```

This will run just fine on older versions as stated but I cant figure out why it isn't working here.

I have tried to research some things but they are mostly inconclusive.

Comment: I don't think there is any `WIN.mainloop()` in the code. Try adding it as the last line in the `run_gui()` function.

Comment: You need to run the mainloop method on the window. Inside the run_gui() method you should put 
`WIN.mainloop()`

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem, in the newest version of python (personnaly i never use version of python below 3.x but i would try to make my best for answering your question). In tkinter, you have now to use `mainloop()` who would make work all the events and show the window.
But if you want to make a video game were you draw element frame by frame on a canvas
you would need to put in your case `WIN.update()` for update the screen and get the events because `mainloop()` act like a infinite loop who break when the user close the window.
Have a good day.